# jQuery if select is not selected add error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the `<select id="jobCategory">` and job `<select id="industry">` fields mandatory by adding a error message.

Not sure if I have to make them also disable in order to do it properly.

- My if statement doesn't work for both field.
- Error message in red doesn't show.

```js
var maleFemale = '';

$('#submitBtn').click(function() {


  var errors = false;
  if (maleFemale == '') {
    errors = true;
    $('#areYou').css('color', '#F00');
  } else {
    $('#areYou').css('color', '#000');
  }
  if ($("#twitterInput").val() == '' || $("#twitterInput").val() == '@yourname' || $("#twitterInput").val() == '@') {
    errors = true;
    $('#enterTwitterHandle').css('color', '#F00');
  } else {
    $('#enterTwitterHandle').css('color', '#000');
  }



  if ($('#jobCategory option:selected').length == 0) {
    alert('nothing selected');
    $('#enterCategory').css('color', '#F00');
  } else {
    $('#enterCategory').css('color', '#000');
  }

  if ($('#industry option:selected').length == 0) {
    alert('nothing selected');
    $('#enterIndustry').css('color', '#F00');
  } else {
    $('#enterIndustry').css('color', '#000');
  }

  if (!errors) {
    $('body').addClass('submitted');
  }
});
```

```css
#submitBtn {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='form'>
  <p id='areYou'>Are you...</p>
  <div id='maleFemaleSelector'>
    <p class='maleFemaleSelectorBtn transform' id='maleBtn'>Male</p>
    <p class='maleFemaleSelectorBtn transform' id='femaleBtn'>Female</p>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
  </div>

  <p id='enterTwitterHandle'>Enter a Twitter handle</p>
  <input type='text' id='twitterInput' value='@yourname' />
  <div style='clear:both'></div>

  <p id='enterCategory'>Select your job category</p>
  <select id="jobCategory" class="select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>job category</option>
    <option value="it"> IT</option>
    <option value="finance">Finance</option>
    <option value="hr">HR</option>
    <option value="marketing">Marketing</option>
    <option value="security">Security</option>
    <option value="developer">Developer</option>
    <option value="others">Others</option>
  </select>

  <div style='clear:both'></div>


  <p id='enterIndustry'>Select your industry</p>
  <select id="industry" class="select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>industry</option>
    <option value="retail">Retail</option>
    <option value="travel-transportation">Travel & Transportation</option>
    <option value="telco-media">Telco / Media</option>
    <option value="banking">Banking</option>
    <option value="health-government">Health & Government</option>
    <option value="energy-utilities">Energy & Utilities</option>

  </select>

  <p id='submitBtn'>Discover your AI iD</p>
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change:

```
if ($('#jobCategory option:selected').length == 0) {
```

to

```
if ($('#jobCategory option:selected').val() == '') {
```

And

```
if ($('#industry option:selected').length == 0)
```

to

```
if ($('#industry option:selected').val() == '')
```

this should work.

The original one finds the length `== '12'` (which is not 0) because the text inside the option is 'job category' which is 12 charactors long.

the new one will search for the values instead, which only `== ''`  on
`<option value="" disabled selected>job category</option>` which is basically nothing selected.

Working example:

```js
var maleFemale = '';

$('#submitBtn').click(function() {


  var errors = false;
  if (maleFemale == '') {
    errors = true;
    $('#areYou').css('color', '#F00');
  } else {
    $('#areYou').css('color', '#000');
  }
  if ($("#twitterInput").val() == '' || $("#twitterInput").val() == '@yourname' || $("#twitterInput").val() == '@') {
    errors = true;
    $('#enterTwitterHandle').css('color', '#F00');
  } else {
    $('#enterTwitterHandle').css('color', '#000');
  }



  if ($('#jobCategory option:selected').val() == '') {
    alert('nothing selected');
    $('#enterCategory').css('color', '#F00');
  } else {
    $('#enterCategory').css('color', '#000');
  }

  if ($('#industry option:selected').val() == '') {
    alert('nothing selected');
    $('#enterIndustry').css('color', '#F00');
  } else {
    $('#enterIndustry').css('color', '#000');
  }

  if (!errors) {
    $('body').addClass('submitted');
  }
});
```

```css
#submitBtn {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='form'>
  <p id='areYou'>Are you...</p>
  <div id='maleFemaleSelector'>
    <p class='maleFemaleSelectorBtn transform' id='maleBtn'>Male</p>
    <p class='maleFemaleSelectorBtn transform' id='femaleBtn'>Female</p>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
  </div>

  <p id='enterTwitterHandle'>Enter a Twitter handle</p>
  <input type='text' id='twitterInput' value='@yourname' />
  <div style='clear:both'></div>

  <p id='enterCategory'>Select your job category</p>
  <select id="jobCategory" class="select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>job category</option>
    <option value="it"> IT</option>
    <option value="finance">Finance</option>
    <option value="hr">HR</option>
    <option value="marketing">Marketing</option>
    <option value="security">Security</option>
    <option value="developer">Developer</option>
    <option value="others">Others</option>
  </select>

  <div style='clear:both'></div>


  <p id='enterIndustry'>Select your industry</p>
  <select id="industry" class="select">
    <option value="" disabled selected>industry</option>
    <option value="retail">Retail</option>
    <option value="travel-transportation">Travel & Transportation</option>
    <option value="telco-media">Telco / Media</option>
    <option value="banking">Banking</option>
    <option value="health-government">Health & Government</option>
    <option value="energy-utilities">Energy & Utilities</option>

  </select>

  <p id='submitBtn'>Discover your AI iD</p>
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
</div>
```

An alternative (but not recommended) is to search for the text itself inside the option:selected.

Like this:

```
if ($('#jobCategory option:selected').text == 'job category') {
```